# iOS -[UIImage initWithCGImage:scale:orientation:] crashes on a background thread

Tags: ios, uiimage, thread-safety, core-graphics, cgimage

I'm creating a `UIImage` on a background queue with `-[UIImage initWithCGImage:scale:orientation:]`, and it's crashing thusly:

Crash 1

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x183778140 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183840ef8 pthread_kill + 112
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1836e9dac abort + 140
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1837acd34 free_list_checksum_botch + 438
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x1837aced8 free_tiny_botch + 84
5  CoreFoundation                 0x183c08038 __CFBasicHashRehash + 2448
6  CoreFoundation                 0x183c09034 __CFBasicHashAddValue + 100
7  CoreFoundation                 0x183ab49c4 CFDictionarySetValue + 248
8  UIKit                          0x18926fd30 _UITraitCollectionCacheForBuiltinStorage + 152
9  UIKit                          0x189272090 +[UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithDisplayScale:] + 52
10 UIKit                          0x1888d5070 -[UIImage initWithCGImage:scale:orientation:] + 236
11 UIKit                          0x1888d4f74 +[UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:] + 72
12 MyApp                          0x10001a168 -[UIImage(Additions) foo_scaledImageData] (Foo.m:1527)
13 MyApp                          0x100017304 -[Foo bar] (Foo.m:731)
14 MyApp                          0x100017094 __95-[Foo bar]_block_invoke_3 (Foo.m:691)
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x183629630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x1836295f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x183637a88 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x183637224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18383d470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18383d020 start_wqthread + 4
```

I also have a crash with the following two threads:

Crash 2, thread 1:

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x237d3c5c __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x23879b47 pthread_kill + 62
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x237680c5 abort + 108
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x238040e9 free_list_checksum_botch + 362
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x23804105 free_list_checksum_botch + 28
5  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x237fbbff tiny_malloc_from_free_list + 202
6  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x237fa987 szone_malloc_should_clear + 218
7  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x237fa879 malloc_zone_malloc + 88
8  CoreFoundation                 0x23a4e291 _CFRuntimeCreateInstance + 236
9  CoreGraphics                   0x24e792a9 CGTypeCreateInstance + 20
10 CoreGraphics                   0x24db7d23 CGColorTransformCreate + 246
11 ImageIO                        0x2533c64b IIO_ConvertCGColorToColorComponents + 26
12 ImageIO                        0x252f5775 CGImagePixelDataProviderCreate + 276
13 ImageIO                        0x25319af1 CGImagePixelDataProviderCreateConforming + 1684
14 ImageIO                        0x252f418d CGImageDestinationAddImage + 2852
15 UIKit                          0x283fe4f5 _UIImageJPEGRepresentation + 620
16 MyApp                          0xf6785 -[UIImage(Additions) foo_scaledImageData] (Foo.m:1538)
17 MyApp                          0xf3ecd -[Foo bar] (Foo.m:731)
18 MyApp                          0xf3d29 __95-[Foo bar]_block_invoke_3 (Foo.m:691)
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x236d7cbf _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x236e36a1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1572
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x236e307b _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x23876e0d _pthread_wqthread + 1024
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x238769fc start_wqthread + 8
```

Crash 2, thread 2:

```
com.apple.root.background-qos
0  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x238041d8 free_tiny_botch
1  CoreFoundation                 0x23b6f560 __CFBasicHashRehash + 2968
2  CoreFoundation                 0x23b706d4 __CFBasicHashAddValue + 100
3  CoreFoundation                 0x23a4f933 CFDictionarySetValue + 206
4  UIKit                          0x28a87ffb _UITraitCollectionCacheForBuiltinStorage + 146
5  UIKit                          0x28a8a2a7 +[UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithDisplayScale:] + 50
6  UIKit                          0x2812390f -[UIImage initWithCGImage:scale:orientation:] + 214
7  UIKit                          0x2812382b +[UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:] + 62
8  MyApp                          0xf676d -[UIImage(Additions) foo_scaledImageData] (Foo.m:1527)
9  MyApp                          0xf3ecd -[Foo bar] (Foo.m:731)
10 MyApp                          0xf3d29 __95-[Foo bar]_block_invoke_3 (Foo.m:691)
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x236d7cbf _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x236e36a1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1572
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x236e307b _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x23876e0d _pthread_wqthread + 1024
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x238769fc start_wqthread + 8
```

Crash 2, thread 2 looks like Crash 1, thread 1, which makes me think that they're related, but Crash 2, thread 2 is an outlier. I have a lot of other crashes that look like Crash 2 without a thread 2 stack, which makes me think that `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` may not be thread-safe either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks similar to an [AFNetworking issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2572#issuecomment-158433196)

> I can't name the source, but it's being taken care of. (or at least a
>   radar has been filed by someone inside Apple)
>
> Side note: I've looked at the UIKit disassembly and that API calls up
>   traitCollection and a few other things and really is everything but
>   thread safe; more so it really should only be called on the main
>   thread ideally. We could swizzle and add the lock directly into the
>   implementation, that would at least remove the fact that any
>   non-AFNetworking consumer would still call this without the lock and
>   might trigger the race condition; but it's also very much not pretty.
>
> Using CGImageSource directly is more work but might be the better
>   solution.

As the `AFNetworking` issue mentions and the stack traces reveal, this looks like `-[UIImage initWithCGImage:scale:orientation:]` calls through to `UITraitCollection`. I can't find anything in `UITraitCollection.h` or in the [`UITraitCollection` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitCollection_ClassReference/) that says `UITraitCollection` is thread safe.

Thus, even though the [`UIImage` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/) says `UIImage`s are thread-safe:

> Because image objects are immutable, you cannot change their
>   properties after creation. Most image properties are set automatically
>   using metadata in the accompanying image file or image data. The
>   immutable nature of image objects also means that they are safe to use
>   from any thread.

The documentation must mean they're safe to use after being created on the main thread, or maybe that they're safe to use if they're only being created serially. (This is how [`AFNetworking` fixed their issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/2860).) For my workaround, I switched to using `CoreGraphics`:

```
CGImageRef image = ...
CGSize scaledSize = ...

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                             scaledSize.width,
                                             scaledSize.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image),
                                             CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image),
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(image),
                                             CGImageGetAlphaInfo(image));

CGImageRef scaledImage;
if (context)
{
    CGContextDrawImage(context,
                       CGRectMake(0,
                                  0,
                                  scaledSize.width,
                                  scaledSize.height),
                       image);
    scaledImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
}
else
{
    scaledImage = NULL;
}
```

Then, to avoid using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` on a background thread, I use `ImageIO` to export JPEG data:

```
NSData *NSDataFromCGImage(CGImageRef scaledImage) 
{
    NSMutableData *scaledImageMutableData = scaledImage ? [NSMutableData new] : nil;
    CGDataConsumerRef scaledImageDataConsumer = scaledImageMutableData ? CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef) scaledImageMutableData) : NULL;
    // from the iOS 9.3 header:
    // The `options' dictionary is reserved for future use; currently, you
    // should pass NULL for this parameter.
    CGImageDestinationRef scaledImageDestination = scaledImageDataConsumer ? CGImageDestinationCreateWithDataConsumer(scaledImageDataConsumer,
                                                                                                                      kUTTypeJPEG,
                                                                                                                      1,
                                                                                                                      NULL) : NULL;
    BOOL success = (^BOOL ()
                    {
                        if (scaledImageDestination)
                        {
                            NSDictionary *addImageOptions = @{(__bridge NSString *)kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality : @(0.9),
                                                              };
                            CGImageDestinationAddImage(scaledImageDestination,
                                                       scaledImage,
                                                       (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)addImageOptions);

                            return (BOOL) CGImageDestinationFinalize(scaledImageDestination);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return NO;
                        }
                    })();
    if (scaledImageDestination)
    {
        CFRelease(scaledImageDestination);
    }
    CGDataConsumerRelease(scaledImageDataConsumer);

    if (success)
    {
        return scaledImageMutableData;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```